# Tile Map Shader?

Tags: c#, unity, tilemap, fragment-shader, cg

I'm trying to write a shader in unity that will take tiles from a sprite sheet and draw them onto a tile map.

I'm new to shaders so this might be totally wrong, I think it might just be a math error on my part, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how shaders work.

Here's my Shader:

```
    Shader "Custom/TileMapShader" {
Properties {
    _TileSheet ("Tile_Sheet", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader {
    Pass {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        uniform sampler2D _TileSheet;
        uniform float2 _MapSize;

        struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
            float4 tilecoord : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float2 tex: TEXCOORD0;
            float2 tileIndex : VECTOR;
        };

        vertexOutput vert (vertexInput v)
        {
            vertexOutput output;

            output.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            output.tex = v.texcoord;
            output.tileIndex = v.tilecoord.xy; // <-- Using UV2 might be a bit hacky
                                               //     to get the tile index but it 
                                               //     seemed better than creating a 
                                               //     texture to do it...

            return output;
        }

        float4 frag (vertexOutput i) : SV_Target
        {
            int xTile = (i.tileIndex.x * 16);
            int yTile = (i.tileIndex.y * 16);

            float2 uv = float2(xTile, yTile + 1) / 16;

            float xoffset = frac( i.tex.x * _MapSize.x ) / 16;
            float yoffset = frac( i.tex.y * _MapSize.y ) / 16;

            uv += float2( xoffset, -yoffset );

            uv.y = 1.0 - uv.y;

            return tex2D(_TileSheet, uv);           
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}  
    }
```

I stumbled across this http://connorhollis.com/code/fast-tilemap-shader/
and modified it to get what I have above.

this is how I create my Mesh: (I don't think this is the issue but who knows)

```
    void BuildMesh()
{
    int numTiles = (int) (mapSize.x * mapSize.y);
    int numTris = numTiles * 2;

    int vsize_x = (int)mapSize.x + 1;
    int vsize_z = (int)mapSize.y + 1;
    int numVerts = vsize_x * vsize_z;

    // Generate the mesh data
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[numVerts];
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[numVerts];
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[numVerts];

    //Tiles
    _tileMap = new Vector2[numVerts];

    int[] triangles = new int[numTris * 3];

    int x, z;
    for (z = 0; z < vsize_z; z++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < vsize_x; x++)
        {
            vertices[z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector3(x * TileSize, 0, -z * TileSize);
            normals[z * vsize_x + x] = Vector3.up;
            uv[z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector2((float)x / (int)mapSize.x, 1f - (float)z / (int)mapSize.y);
            //Tiles TEMP
            switch (Random.Range(0, 2))
            {                                             // Tile Selection
                case 0:                                   // X              Y
                    _tileMap[z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector2((1 * 0.0625f), (0 * 0.0625f));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    _tileMap[z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector2((2 * 0.0625f), (0 * 0.0625f));
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    for (z = 0; z < (int)mapSize.y; z++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < (int)mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            int squareIndex = z * (int)mapSize.x + x;
            int triOffset = squareIndex * 6;
            triangles[triOffset + 0] = z * vsize_x + x + 0;
            triangles[triOffset + 2] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 0;
            triangles[triOffset + 1] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;

            triangles[triOffset + 3] = z * vsize_x + x + 0;
            triangles[triOffset + 5] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;
            triangles[triOffset + 4] = z * vsize_x + x + 1;
        }
    }


    //Populate mesh with the data
    _mesh.vertices = vertices;
    _mesh.triangles = triangles;
    _mesh.normals = normals;
    _mesh.uv = uv;
    _mesh.uv2 = _tileMap;

    _material.SetVector("_MapSize", new Vector4(mapSize.x, mapSize.y));
}
```

And this is how it all ends up looking

[image: Messed up Tile Map]

and this is the tile sheet I'm using to test. There are 16x16 tiles, and each tile is 16x16 pixels

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzQpJ.png

Thank you for the Help, I've been stuck on this for a few days now,
I tried to keep things short and to the point.

Comment: Hey @Dusty I wrote that! Here is the full article if you didn't see it yet. [link](http://connorhollis.com/fast-tilemap-shader/) I also uploaded the sample project I built to dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwta78c2zn6l5dj/art_demo.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @ConnorHollis, Thanks! I'll take a look at the full article and Demo and see what I get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was the Mesh creation and the shader was working fine.

In my above example vertices are shared between different tiles, below vertices are only shared between the 2 triangles that make each tile.

```
        void BuildMesh()
{
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(int) mapSize.x * (int) mapSize.y * 4];
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[vertices.Length];
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];

    _tileMap = new Vector2[vertices.Length];

    int[] triangles = new int[vertices.Length * 6];

    float width =  (int)mapSize.x;
    float height = (int)mapSize.y;

    float x, z;
    for (z = 0; z < mapSize.y; z++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            int squareVal = (int)((z * width + x) * 4);

            vertices[squareVal + 0] = new Vector3(x, 0, -z);
            vertices[squareVal + 1] = new Vector3(x + 1, 0, -z);
            vertices[squareVal + 2] = new Vector3(x, 0, -z - 1);
            vertices[squareVal + 3] = new Vector3(x + 1, 0, -z - 1);

            normals[squareVal + 0] = Vector3.up;
            normals[squareVal + 1] = Vector3.up;
            normals[squareVal + 2] = Vector3.up;
            normals[squareVal + 3] = Vector3.up;

            uv[squareVal + 0] = new Vector2((x + 0f) / width, 1f - (z + 0f) / height);
            uv[squareVal + 1] = new Vector2((x + 1f) / width, 1f - (z + 0f) / height);
            uv[squareVal + 2] = new Vector2((x + 0f) / width, 1f - (z + 1f) / height);
            uv[squareVal + 3] = new Vector2((x + 1f) / width, 1f - (z + 1f) / height);

            _tileMap[squareVal + 0] = Vector2.zero;
            _tileMap[squareVal + 1] = Vector2.zero;
            _tileMap[squareVal + 2] = Vector2.zero;
            _tileMap[squareVal + 3] = Vector2.zero;

            int triangleVal = squareVal * 6;

            triangles[triangleVal + 0] = squareVal + 0;
            triangles[triangleVal + 1] = squareVal + 1;
            triangles[triangleVal + 2] = squareVal + 2;

            triangles[triangleVal + 3] = squareVal + 1;
            triangles[triangleVal + 4] = squareVal + 3;
            triangles[triangleVal + 5] = squareVal + 2;
        }
    }

    //Populate mesh with the data
    _mesh.vertices = vertices;
    _mesh.triangles = triangles;
    _mesh.normals = normals;
    _mesh.uv = uv;
    _mesh.uv2 = _tileMap;

    _material.SetVector("_MapSize", new Vector4(mapSize.x, mapSize.y));    
}
```

and to set a tile I do this for each tile

```
void setTile(Vector2 tile, Vector2 sprite)
{
    int squareVal = (int)((tile.y * mapSize.x + tile.x) * 4);

    _tileMap[squareVal + 0] = sprite * 0.0625f;
    _tileMap[squareVal + 1] = sprite * 0.0625f;
    _tileMap[squareVal + 2] = sprite * 0.0625f;
    _tileMap[squareVal + 3] = sprite * 0.0625f;
}
```

and call this when I want to push the changes.

```
    _mesh.uv2 = _tileMap;
```